# php - naming Multiple file input fields on a form

Tags: php, html, forms, file

I am wanting to have multiple fields on one form that can insert files.

I have the below script, but I want to be able to identify what field the inserted file belongs to in the saved name.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' id="form" name="form">

  Input 1<input type="file" name="upload[]" >
  Input 2<input type="file" name="upload[]" >
  Input 3<input type="file" name="upload[]" >

  <button id="submit-button">Upload</button>

</form>


<?php

//if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST) ){
$count = 0;
$max_file_size = 5000000;
  if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
  // Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files

  foreach ($_FILES['upload']['name'] as $f => $name) {

      $path = 'documents'; //path of directory

      if ($_FILES['upload']['error'][$f] == 4) {
          continue; // Skip file if any error found
      } else {
          if ($_FILES['upload']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
              $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
              continue; // Skip large files
          }
          else {
              // No error found! Move uploaded files
              //$name_of_file = $_FILES['username']['name'][$f];
              $temp_name = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$f]; //[$count];
              move_uploaded_file($temp_name, "$path/"."$name");
              $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
          }
      }
  }
  }
```

At the moment it just saves the files into the one location, so I cant differentiate them and identify which field they are from.

can anyone please help?

Comment: Modify the name field? `upload[one], upload[two]` etc. And just handle the files smartly on the server side

Comment: Hi @Darren , That is what I am trying to do, but am at a loss to know how.

Comment: print the form field with in a loop so that every field have a proper index.

Comment: @MUNISHKUMAR How do you recommend this be done please? I can print them up but then they need to be loaded onto the system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked it out. I have taken the comments above and placed an Text input field at each of the File Fields. These could also be hidden fields if you need set names.

Then I scroll through them and save the names and apply those names on the server side.

Thanks to the comments, they helped me see the solution.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' id="form" name="form">

  <input type="text" name="input0" value=""><input type="file" name="upload[]" ><br><br>
  <input type="text" name="input1" value=""><input type="file" name="upload[]" ><br><br>
  <input type="text" name="input2" value=""><input type="file" name="upload[]" ><br><br>

  <button id="submit-button">Upload</button>

</form>


<?php

$count = 0;
$max_file_size = 500000000000;
  if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
  // Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files


$x = 0;
$input = "input";


while ($x <= 2){

$field_name = $input.$x;

$field[$x] = $_POST[$field_name];

$x++;
}

  foreach ($_FILES['upload']['name'] as $f => $name) {

      $path = 'documents'; //path of directory

      if ($_FILES['upload']['error'][$f] == 4) {
          continue; // Skip file if any error found
      } else {
          if ($_FILES['upload']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
              $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
              continue; // Skip large files
          }
          else {
              $temp_name = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$f]; //[$count];
              move_uploaded_file($temp_name, "$path/"."$field[$count]"."$name");
              $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
          }
      }
  }
  }
```